# How to write a JSDoc for an object with different types of keys?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

The JSDoc api says you [can document objects](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html) like so:

```
{Object.<string, number>}
```

and document multiple type:

```
{(number|boolean)}
```

But if I try to specify an object that could have strings OR numbers as the key, it does not work. VSCode/JSDoc just reports the type as 'any'.

VSCode does not understand:

```js
/**
 * Object with string or number for keys
 * @param {Object.<(string|number), any>} Container
 */
```

I've also tried this in `@typedef`, or defining the key in it's own `@typedef` to no effect.

Because I'm using `&` to get an `intersection` of types (like `{Object.<string, any> & {'foo': number}}` I don't want to have to use the boolean or to say:

```js
/**
 * Object with string or number for keys
 * @param {(Object.<string, any>|Object.<number, any>) & {'foo': number}} Container
 */
```

The type documented ends up looking something like:

```
 type Container = ({
    [x: string]: any;
  } & {
    'foo': number;
  }) | ({
    [x: number]: any;
  } & {
    'foo': number;
  })
```

Which is needlessly verbose.

Is there way to document this with a more succinct output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In JavaScript, object keys are always strings (or, in the case of numbers, coerced into strings), so you might be needlessly complicating things.  See the [ECMAScript spec on Objects](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-object-type):

> Properties are identified using key values. A property key value is either an ECMAScript String value or a Symbol value. All String and Symbol values, including the empty String, are valid as property keys. A property name is a property key that is a String value.
>
> An integer index is a String-valued property key that is a canonical numeric String

That said, this seems like the most straightforward solution:

```js
// Combined
/**
 * @param {Object.<string, any> & {foo:  number}} Container
 */

// Split/reusable
/**
 * @typedef {Object.<string, any>} GenericObject
 * @param {GenericObject & {foo: number}} Container
 */
```

Both of the above result in this type/documentation:

```
Container: {
    [x: string]: any;
} & {
    foo: number;
}
```

Declaring `Object.<string, any>` seems a bit redundant to me since object keys are inherently `string`s and values are inherently `any`, so declaring it this way doesn't provide much value to a developer.